# Segment images & annotate each segments & save annotation as labels of each segments

Tags: javascript, python, machine-learning, computer-vision

Here is the image that I want to segment:
[Plant Cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA94c.jpg)

The result that I want to achieve is to segment each cells as individual image (For future as input of Convolutional Neural net) and annotate them manually. Finally I can output the annotations as labels for each cell in order to classify them in the future.

Dose anyone know the best way to complete this task with javascript or python? Or other programming languages? I read a lot of papers about how to segment images like Grabcut. But really I still do not have any idea how to implement segmentation as well as annotation after segmentation.

The segmentation I mean output multiple cell images instead of just segmenting them in single image. Does anyone have ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this tool [here](https://github.com/kyamagu/js-segment-annotator),i think its appropriate for that